# Need to add Material Design Style in forms of bootstrap based web application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I have worked on front end development of a forum which is using Bootstrap.  I need to add Material Style to only its form elements.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any fiddle/demo code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

After you have inserted the ***material.css*** and ***material.min.js*** in addition to your bootstrap resources, you should be good to go:

Here's an example input:

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="nick-name" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Nick Name</label>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="nick-name" id="nick-name" pattern="[A-Z,a-z, ]*">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="nick-name">Nick Name</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Letters and spaces only</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```